# Use XGBoost's implementation of AUC on a test set

Tags: xgboost, auc

I want to be able to use a classifier fitted with XGBoost to compute AUC (Area under the ROC curve) on a test set, but using XGBoost's implementation of AUC (which is used to compute the metric on the test set provided at training time). So, given a model fitted like

```
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(...)
model.fit(...)
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
model.evaluate(my_test_data, metric="auc")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you not happy with the sklean's implementation of roc auc? In general, it is not possible to re-evaluate the internal metric on a new dataset. The only thing you can do is to pull out the metric values produced in the evaluation during fitting (if you used `my_test_data` as `eval_sets`) for this you can use [model.eval_results()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.evals_result)

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi Its not that I'm not happy with it, its more like I want to be able to use the same metric consistently. So if I have multiple trained models and I want to compare them across a common test set, it would be nice to see which model is the best on the validation metric they all used--in this case xgboost's auc. If there is a difference in the way xgboost and sklearn calculates auc, I would not necessarily expect the "best" model from xgboost to have the best auc based on sklearn.

Comment: I have used roc auc in both and i did not see any difference between what xgboost reported in training and what sklearn output. But in an unlikely hypothetical situation there could be a metric `X` that could differ. Then you can re-optimise the number of xgboost trees yourself using `X` values calculated with sklearn with different number of trees in prediction (because a metric in xgboost is used for monitoring only and to decide when to stop training- for the gradient calculation metric is irrelevant and *loss* function is used). And then you can use sklearn's implementation for all models.